# How can I make non-breaking spaces visible? Maybe through CSS, (without replacing the non-breaking space character with another character)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make non-breaking spaces visible, maybe through CSS? For editing purposes of text.

Word as example, has a button where you can click and see the non-breaking spaces as examples, they show up as some circle unicode. Not sure if it replaces the font or something.

I'm not sure if it's possible to change the color, I guess it is, but there's nothing to colorize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to wrap them into some span tags, you can use the CSS `after` directive like so:

```html
<p>hello<span class="space">&nbsp;</span>world</p>
```

```css
.space::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-3px, 9px);
  width: 3px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Take a look at [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/chamboug/pen/RwreLYP).

Comment: It works, well with javascript, which is fine. Is it also possible to do it without javascript, based when I look into that CSS doesn't have a selector for a single character or filtering right?

Comment: No I don't think so, you'll have to wrap it into a `span` tag